# I cannot access to some pages through Route in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I'm having 2 pages `RestaurantReview` and  `singlePostView` and I'm using `Rotue` to access both of them in the `App.js` file. However, I am just able to open the `singlePostView` by this way

```
<Route exact path="/" component={singlePostView}>
</Route>
```

but for the `RestauarantReview` I can access by both of these ways

```
<Route exact path="/">
 <RestaurantReview name = {res.name} />
</Route>

and 

<Route exact path="/" component={RestaurantReview}>
</Route>
```

So

- how can I access the `singlePostView` by putting its tag inside the `Route` tag.
- for the current way of opening the `singlePostView`, how can I pass the parameters to that component

Here are some additional code about `RestaurantReview` and `singlePostView`

```
class RestaurantReview extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            getData: false
        }
    }
    render(){return()}
}
export default RestaurantReview
```

```
function singlePostView({props}) {
   return()
}
export default singlePostView
```

EDIT: i changed the first letter of `singlePostView` to uppercase and it works

Comment: You should be able to render `singlePostView` as a child of `Route` component, even if it is a functional component. I don't know if it helps, but try naming your components with upper case first letters, so `SinglePostView`. Then, you'll be able to pass props to the component just as you did with `RestaurantView`. Also, you can redirect programatically to the `singlePostView` route and send props like this: `this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/single-post-view', state: { someData: someData }})` and then retrieve them by `this.props.location.state.someData`

Comment: it works, thank you so so much

Comment: Glad to be helpful to you :) please upvote my comment, thanks!

Comment: I really want to vote your cmt up but I don't have enough reputation to do that. You will have a vote in my mine =)))